# Ensuring that JavaX Package is Present

Tags: java, compatibility

My copy of Java 8 on OS X has the `javax` package.

My copy of Java 8 on Debian/Ubuntu (Linux Mint) does not.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/vecmath/Point3f

How could I get hold of a portable version (`JAR`) that contains this package and include it if it doesn't exist at run time?

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that `javax` is missing; on your Debian installation you should have most of its libraries such as Swing and `javax.crypto`.  What you are missing is Java 3D, a library that does *not* come with every java installation.  You should be able download the Java 3D API [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-jsp-138252.html), and then you will have `Point3f` and the other classes in `javax.vecmath`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there a way (such as an apt-get package) to install it automatically?

Comment: I don't think so, but all you have to do is download the .bin file for your system, use `chmod a+x [path]` to make it executable, and run it from the command line.  You will be given a license agreement (if it's too long, just type yes then return) and follow the onscreen directions to complete the installation.  (note that I'm on OS X, so I haven't been able to fully carry the Linux installation out myself.)